# What are all the rewards for the Tinkerer's quests?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I've tried some of the daily Tinkerer's quests and so far I've gotten Transformation Potions, Loot Potions and a Slime Ninja skin. Is there a list of all the rewards that you can get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the slime skins rotate over time. According to [RealmEye](https://www.realmeye.com/wiki/the-tinkerer) the fourth daily reward uses a random [tarot card](https://www.realmeye.com/wiki/dungeon-treasures) in exchange for an [Alchemist](https://www.realmeye.com/wiki/the-alchemist)  token.

Answer (score 0):

When the Alchemist is in Nexus, the third quest item would cost tarot cards for a token. If not, it is just Transformation Potions, Loot Tier Potions, and Slime Skins.